# Regex to match chars at the start and digits at the end

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression for the following conditions:

- The length of the string is exactly 8
- The string may not start with PAK
- The first character must be an upper case char [A-Z]
- The second to fourth char can be an upper case char
- The remaining chars may only be digits

Examples:

- PAK12345 -> not allowed
- T1234567 -> allowed
- ABCD1234 -> allowed
- ABC12345 -> allowed
- AB12345A -> not allowed
- **ABCDE123 -> not allowed**
- ABC123   -> not allowed

Actually I have the following regex:

```
(?!PAK)([A-Z]{1,4}[A-Z0-9]{7})$
```

The problem with this regex is, that "ABCDE123" is a match.

How can I say, that the first 1 to 4 characters are only upper case chars and the remaining (until the total lenght of 8) are digits?

Comment: you mean 1 to 5 are uppercase?

Comment: 1 to 4 may be uppercase. 1 must be uppercase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the regex range operator and do an exact character length match. Add a positive lookahead at the very first to ensure that the length must be exactly 8.

```
^(?=.{8}$)(?!PAK)([A-Z]{1,4}[0-9]+)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/q5AdxC/3)

Comment: Then "ABC12345" is not allowed any more

Comment: Almost right. Have to change {1,5} to {1,4}. Thank you very much

Comment: if I changed above then how `ABCDE123` would get matched?

Comment: ABCDE123 should not match. This is ok

Comment: oh, wrongly understood. I thought you want this `ABCDE123` string to get matched.

Comment: Ok. I update it. But I've initially added ABCDE123 to the not allowed list